# Spark java framework not running on tomcat server

Tags: javascript, java, apache, tomcat

Hello I am totally new to java web app so i googled how to get started with java web apps and i came across Spark framework and i installed everything as documented but still somehow i cannot get my server running. Can anyone help me?

Please find below the error logs i am getting

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SparkFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.servlet.SparkFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4841)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5535)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="3.0">
    <display-name>new-match-app</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
            <param-value>main.java.Main</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Apache Spark, but in this particular case the cause of error is that tomcat can't find the class `spark.servlet.SparkFilter`.

It has to reside in some jar (I guess, related to Spark) inside WEB-INF/lib directory in your WAR.

In general the WAR is just an archive (like a zip, it can be even opened by tools like WinRar or WinZip to examine its contents) that contains your classes and third-party libraries that you use.

Here I assume you're using some filter offered by spark third-party so, the filter has to exist and be accessible by tomcat's Web Class Loader responsible for loading the WAR.

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off base but I think you are mixing up Apache Spark with Spark Framework.

[Spark Framework is a Javascript framework](http://sparkjava.com/).

[**Apache Spark** is a parallel processing api](http://spark.apache.org/) based on Scala, with interfaces in Scala, Java, Python and now R.

I just say this based on the other answer and the use of the apache-spark tag :) I wish there was not two projects out there named Spark.

Hope you got this running. Hope this helps, bottom line it looks like your classpath is not set up correctly and there's not enough info to be more specific that that.